# Performance issue in Xpath grammar file using antlr

Tags: xpath, antlr, antlr4

I am running into a performance issue while creating the grammar for Xpath.

The whole grammar was working fine till we added support for the xpaths like:

```
((div)[1]//span)[1]
```

or

```
((//div)[1]/div)[last()]
```

After adding support for this in the grammar file, the above xpaths started working fine but other xpaths started giving performance issues.

Like this one :

```
//label[normalize-space(.)='Phone']/parent::lightning-input/parent::slot/parent::slot/parent::span/parent::div/parent::force-record-layout-item/parent::slot/parent::force-record-layout-row/parent::slot/parent::div/parent::div/parent::div/parent::force-record-layout-section/parent::slot/parent::force-record-layout-block/parent::forcegenerated-detailpanel_contact___012b0000000jhhvia4___full___view___recordlayout2/parent::records-lwc-record-layout/parent::slot/parent::records-record-layout-event-broker/parent::div/parent::div/following-sibling::force-form-footer//button
```

which started taking 30 seconds in parsing (it took 170ms earlier).

These were the lines of code added/modified in the attached grammar file which started giving performance issue:

```
union
 : expressions+=pathExpression (WS? operator='|' WS? expressions+=pathExpression)*  
 ;

pathExpression
 : expressionAtom
 | expressionAtom nodeSet
 ;

expressionAtom
 : functionCall
 | nodeSet
 | literal
 | parenthesis
 ;
```

Earlier it was:

```
union
 : expressions+=expressionAtom (WS? operator='|' WS? expressions+=expressionAtom)*
 ;

expressionAtom
 : functionCall
 | nodeSet
 | literal 
 | parenthesis
 ;
```

and used to give no performance issues.

On debugging the XpathParser I figured out that it is because the DFAState has** `requiresFullContext` as `true` **in this case.

The documentation states that the true value of this “Indicates that this state was created during SLL prediction that discovered a conflict between the configurations in the state.”

Can you help me resolve this issue and what is causing it to search the full context which takes time?

Comment: The XPath starting with `//label[normalize-space(.)='Phone']/...` is massive. I suppose we can find something shorter and more efficient. Please post a sample of your data.

Comment: Questions: (1) Is this a modification of https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/xpath/xpath.g4? Or are you adapting from https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-xpath-30-20140408/#nt-bnf (2) WS is a regular token, not skip. Am I reading that right?

Comment: Is this XPath 1.0 you are implementing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Antlr well, but how about replacing

```
pathExpression
 : expressionAtom
 | expressionAtom nodeSet
 ;
```

with

```
pathExpression
 : expressionAtom nodeSet?
 ;
```